# 'unknown host' error when trying to link EB and EFS from different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

Today my EC2 instance had some trouble, EB did his job, create new instance and terminated the old one.
The the problem is that my /mnt/efs folder is empty.

I tried to mount it by hand but I get this error:

> unknown host fs-xxx.efs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

Here is my command to mount the volume:

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport fs-846896dd.efs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:/ /mnt/efs
```

Another important thing: my elastic beanstalk environment and EFS are not on the same region:

EB -> Paris
EFS -> Frankfurt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I cannot link EFS and EB because they must be on the same zone, so I moved EB on Frankfurt.